# How can I fix R producing an empty dataframe when using "merge"?

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames by the column "CODE" which both of them share. The codes contain letters as well as numbers, i.e. P10024. Since one data frame has substantially more rows than the other, I used `all.y = FALSE`. The code looks like this:

```
new_df <- merge(df1, df2, by = c ("CODE"), all.y = FALSE)
```

The resulting data frame contains all columns of the original data frames, but no rows. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you meant `all.x = TRUE`?

Comment: It may be that your 'CODE' values are not exactly matching .e. if there are leading lagging spaces, it will be no match (`A` and ` A`).  Use `trimws` on both the 'CODE' columns and try again `df1$CODE <- trimws(df1$CODE)` and `df2$CODE <- trimws(df2$CODE)`

Comment: If you need more help, post some sample data. Even just sharing the code column, `dput(df1[1:10, "CODE"])` and `dput(df2[1:10, "CODE"])` for the first 10 rows of each.

Comment: **Thank you @akrun!** That was the problem! I forgot to mention in my original post that I also tried to combat lagging spaces by using `df1$CODE <- str_trim(df1$CODE)` and `df2$CODE <- str_trim(df2$CODE)`. However, that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @akrun I was able to merge both data frames by using `df1$CODE <- trimws(df1$CODE)` and  `df2$CODE <- trimws(df2$CODE)`. This code got rid of leading lagging spaces that caused trouble!